# OctoPack failing in TFS Build

Tags: azure-devops, octopus-deploy

I'm using Visual Studio Online with Visual Studio 2013. The build fails with

`You are trying to build with OctoPack, but the NuGet targets file that OctoPack depends on is not available on this computer. This is probably because the OctoPack package has not been committed to source control, or NuGet Package Restore is not enabled`

According to this link https://octopusdeploy.com/blog/octopack-3.0 I need to make some changes to get package restore working properly, but another link within the previous one says that no configuration is required if using VS2013 and Visual Studio Online [Nuget.org](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore-with-team-build)

When I build in VS all of the packages get restored first and then the project builds. Also if I build the project and invoke Octopack via command line everything works fine. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

If you do run `NuGet Package Restore` before building, this should work. However, make sure the path in your project file referring to `OctoPack.targets` is correct - you might have moved your packages folder or the project file and the relative paths no longer match. Easiest way to fix it would be to run `Update-Package -Reinstall Octopack`.

Answer (score 2):

`NuGet Package Restore` was recently changed so you wouldn't need to include NuGet in the solution to do a package restore. However, OctoPack still needs `NuGet` on the path so it can find it. You can try explicitly specifying the path to `NuGet` by adding this parameter when calling OctoPack.

```
/p:OctoPackNuGetExePath=<path>\nuget.exe
```

Comment: Octopack includes Nuget though. If you look in the package it downloads it has NuGet.exe in the tools folder. Only way I could get this to work was to check Octopack and all of its children into source control. Sucks, but couldn't get it working any other way.

Comment: Same problem. Same solution.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to check in the Octopack targets file.

\packages\OctoPack.2.0.26\targets\OctoPack.targets

Comment: Checking in NuGet packages (or parts of it) in Source Control is not the way to go.